# Multiple update rows with a column as parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to update multiple rows in my table:

```
    Nip    |       AttendanceDate  |          InTime       |           OutTime
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1105321|2016-08-30 00:00:00.000|1900-01-01 00:00:00.000|1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
    1105321|2016-08-31 00:00:00.000|1900-01-01 00:00:00.000|1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
    1105321|2016-09-01 00:00:00.000|1900-01-01 00:00:00.000|1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
    1105321|2016-09-02 00:00:00.000|1900-01-01 00:00:00.000|1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

I want to update `InTime` & `OutTime` .

I know I can simply do this

```
update Attendance 
set InTime = '2016-08-30 08:00:00.000',
    OutTime = '2016-08-30 18:00:00.000'
where Nip = '1105321' and AttendanceDate = '2016-08-30'
```

But with my query, I must do it one by one. So, my question is can I update it just once? So I don't need to do the update one by one. Is it possible? Sorry for my bad English.

**UPDATE**:

So I don't need to do this

```
update Attendance 
set InTime = '2016-08-30 08:00:00.000',
    OutTime = '2016-08-30 18:00:00.000'
where Nip = '1105321' and AttendanceDate = '2016-08-30'

update Attendance 
set InTime = '2016-08-31 08:00:00.000',
    OutTime = '2016-08-31 18:00:00.000'
where Nip = '1105321' and AttendanceDate = '2016-08-31'

update Attendance 
set InTime = '2016-09-01 08:00:00.000',
    OutTime = '2016-09-01 18:00:00.000'
where Nip = '1105321' and AttendanceDate = '2016-09-01'

update Attendance 
set InTime = '2016-09-02 08:00:00.000',
    OutTime = '2016-09-02 18:00:00.000'
where Nip = '1105321' and AttendanceDate = '2016-09-02'
```

Comment: `one by one` ... Are you asking about updating multiple _columns_, or multiple _rows_ ?

Comment: update rows and columns. Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data type of `AttendanceDate` is `dateTtime`, you can use simple `UPDATE` statement and [`DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function:

```
UPDATE Attendance
SET InTime = DATEADD(HOUR, 8, AttendanceDate),
    OutTime = DATEADD(HOUR, 18, AttendanceDate)
WHERE Nip = '1105321'
```

The statement updates all rows where condition `Nip = '1105321'` is met (as defined by `WHERE` statement). If you want to update every row, just remove `WHERE` statement.

`InTime` is calculated by adding 8 hours to `AttendanceDate`, and `OutTime` - by adding 18 hours to `AttendanceDate`.

If you store the date as string, you will need to do some casting from string to `datetime`, and then cast back when you are done, or choose to use string manipulation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the tip!